# Prerequisites for Bredon's "Topology and Geometry"?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, self-learning

My background in topology is the first 6 chapters of Munkres's "topology" and in algebra Herstein's "Topics in Algebra". Both of them I self studied.

A look at the table of contents of Bredon's "Topology and Geometry" got me to really want to read it (I really like the emphasis on the differential side of things). I don't have any background in differential topology/geometry though...

What are the prerequisites I should be familiar with before tackling this book?

Comment: I would go ahead and start reading, and patch things up as you go. Maybe read up on covering spaces, but I think Bredon does them from scratch (?) Igor suggested Milnor's book, it's a terrific read. You could look at Munkres' Part II before diving into Bredon.

Answer (score 4):

You should read Milnor's topology from a differentiable viewpoint (two or three times) first, then Bott/Tu. Then you are good to go.

Comment: Maybe this is a little ambitious, I mean the Bott/Tu part : it's a non trivial read, rather long aswell, and not exactly easier than Bredon. I agree with Milnor.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat I admit to having been sarcastic, in the sense that B/T being a BETTER book than Bredon, IMHO.

Comment: It may be of interest that Tu has written a book to lead into B/T. It's called [An Introduction to Manifolds](http://www.amazon.com/An-Introduction-Manifolds-Universitext-Loring/dp/1441973990/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1398587842&sr=8-1-fkmr1&keywords=invitation+to+manifolds+tu).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, if you want to study Bredon's book by yourself, you need a good background in elementary topology and some knowledge of differential geometry and algebraic topology.

Since you already studied the first chapters of Munkre's book *Topology*, you shouldn't have any problems studying Bredon's first chapter "General Topology". For chapter 2, Tu's book *Introduction to Manifolds* may be very helpful, or any other elementary book with exercises and solutions. From there, Bredon's book focuses more on algebraic topology with a geometric flavor. Since you have no previous knowledge of algebraic topology, I would say, spend some time (maybe a couple of weeks) reading books such as Armstrong, *Basic Topology*, Janich, *Topology*, or the second part of Munkres'; then study Bredon's book from chapter 3. Alternatively, you can concentrate on Bredon's book and take a look at these three books if you find some passages difficult to understand.

Finally, it is worth saying, Bredon's book is a challenging one. In my humble opinion, it will take you years to really grasp everything it contains. Good luck.